# How do I do a FOREACH loop on specific controls on my web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, web-controls

This is basically what I want to do:

```
foreach (checkbox cbx in Controls.Checkboxes)
{
    if (checkbox.checked)
       {
            //code
       }
}
```

On my web page, there are 2 check boxes. I want to run a process for each selected item on the page.

Comment: you should be able to use `OfType`, e.g. `Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()`

Comment: Yes, you could do what @sa_ddam213 said. But you may be better off just creating a List<Checkbox> and adding your checkboxes to that list, so that if you add more checkboxes that you don't want to be looped over it will support that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to loop through each checkbox of checkboxlist control and get the values.

If so, here is an example.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="CheckBoxList1">
    <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Three" Value="3" />
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            string text = item.Text;
            string value = item.Value;
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

If you are asking about individual checkboxes, click on my previous edited answer.